# Can tensorlfow gradient.tape work with placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to calculate the gradient corresponding to the loss and inputs. But I would like to run it with batch in dataset, and do it recursively.

```
test_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[1, 256, 256,3], dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(test_inputs)
    test_outputs = generator(test_inputs, layers=4, output_channel=3)
    test_error = loss(gen_frames=test_outputs, gt_frames=test_gt)
gradient = tape.gradient(test_error, test_inputs)
```

And it is running with sess and feed_dict

```
loss = sess.run((test_error), feed_dict={test_inputs: images})
```

Is there any way to make the gradient tape work with placeholder?